# brackets wildcards not working for sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, wildcard, sql-like

I want to select all rows where the name mentions the word "Cheesecake" or "cheesecake".

I'm trying to run this sql log with sqlite3 but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT * FROM food
WHERE name LIKE "%[Cc]heesecake%";
```

Comment: You can't just make up some syntax and expect it to be understood by SQLite. ([`GLOB` *might* work](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#glob) but you have to use the correct notation for its wildcards.)

Comment: @Shawn to be fair `LIKE "%[Cc]%"`  isn't just some arbitrary "made up syntax". It is supported in many other products like MSSql or MySQL. So if OP used one of these products before, it might be understandable, to assume, that this syntax might also be supported in SQLite. Nevertheless, once OP noticed it isn't, it might have been better to look in the docs ...

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators):

> Any other character matches itself or its lower/upper case equivalent (i.e. case-insensitive matching)"

So `like "%cheesecake%"` should match `"a Cheesecake"` as well as `"a cheesecake"`